# UIView frame issue different for device and simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios7

Hi ! I am new to IOS development and creating an app for IOS5 and Its later version as well as IOS7.I have set frames for different IOS versions and it works well.

The problem is that when I set **frame** for `UIView` which contains a growing `textView` and run on a *simulator* it does not display or may be it is at the bottom of the device, but when I run it on a *device* using the same **frame**, it works.

How do I set frame that works both on device and simulator ?

Comment: some code would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running the app in the same device, (same inch device) ?